# Programmatic vs Declarative data-binding in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

What is the difference between Programmatic vs Declarative data-binding in asp.net?

[As far as I understand](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=DjDELzhZ2tQC&pg=PT103&lpg=PT103&dq=CheckBoxList.DataTextField&source=bl&ots=J_1HOztDji&sig=ACfU3U13f_E7OT5e-ZEzo7CutSMpT6BGxA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6sp7XxKHjAhWzW3wKHe6nDL4Q6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=CheckBoxList.DataTextField&f=false):

> **Programmatic** means to use programming source code to achieve data-binding.
>
> **Declarative** means to use client-side scripts to achieve data-binding.

Am I correct?

Comment: [This](https://vkinfotek.com/gridview/databinding-a-gridview.html) has example of declarative binding

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but it also has to do with the idea of separation of concerns. Your code is what provides data to a consumer (which could be unknown to the code). Your consumer (in this case the front-end) then receives the data and can then decide how to handle and display the provided data which is where declarative data-binding comes in. This way you decouple your 'view/presenter' from you Model/data producer.